# How to restore default crontab file

Tags: debian, cron

I have recently lost my cronjobs. 
now when i do

```
crontab -e
```

i am presented with an empty file. i would like to get the default file back with the nifty comments and explanaitions at the top!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`crontab -r` should remove the current user's crontab. The next time you run `crontab -e` you should get the default crontab.